# How do I show the previous 2 orders a customer made?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL server and I am stuck on a question.
I need to write a query that shows each customers last order that he placed and the order before the last one he made.
Thank you for your help!

Edit: So far I have this:

```sql
SELECT SalesOrderID, CustomerID, per.FirstName, per.LastName, OrderDate as "Latest Order Date"
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate desc) as 'Rank'
    FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader head
) a join Person.Person per
on CustomerID = per.BusinessEntityID
WHERE Rank = 1
```

As you can see, I am pretty close. I just need to add a column that shows the order before the latest order date.

Sorry, I'm new to the site (long time viewer, first time poster)

ty!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the stackoverflow. Please provide us with some data to test on

Comment: Do it step by step. First find customer last 3 order (last order plus 2 previous). Use `row_number() over (partition by  . . . order by . . .)` , [cte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Give it a try and if you encounter issue, post your query here

Comment: @ekochergin OP is `using adventureworks database` , OP is probably new or still learning `SQL`. Best is to provide guidance / hint rather than give solution directly.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track.  Where are you stuck?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Squirrel completely agree. I wasn't sure I can give an advice without seeing source data first. On the other hand, providing test data is one of requirements here in Stackoverflow, so OP needs to learn it as well.

Comment: @Squirrel Hi, I edited my original post. I am new and currently learning! All help appreciated!

Comment: @ekochergin I edited my original post, as well as a pic to show the end result

Comment: @Ajsrise thanks for updating question. It is very well done

Comment: @ekochergin Hey! Sorry if I wasn't clear. The end result is not my result haha. Our questions have the end result to show us how it should look like (without the code). I cant figure out how to add the column that shows the order before the "Latest Order Date".

Comment: @Bee_Riii I've updated my post on what I did so far, I am still stuck on getting the order date before the latest order date.

Comment: You don't NEED lag/lead. You could simply retrieve rows 1 and 2 after using row_number and then self join. Often there are multiple ways to achieve a goal using SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to combine both `ROW_NUMBER` and `LEAD`**

`LEAD` is better in this case, because `LAG` needs the rows sorted in the opposite direction from the `ROW_NUMBER`

```sql
SELECT head.SalesOrderID, CustomerID, per.FirstName, per.LastName, OrderDate as LastOrder, head.PreviousOrder
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) as rnk,
        LEAD(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) as PreviousOrder
    FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader head
) head
JOIN Person.Person per ON head.CustomerID = per.BusinessEntityID
WHERE head.rnk = 1;
```